# Sticky element inside overflow element

Tags: html, css, overflow, sticky

I would like to make the timeline-header sticky to the top of the page in the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/m152usbd/1/

But because the timeline has overflow enabled, sticky stops working on timeline-header.

```
.timeline{
  overflow: auto;
}

.timeline-header{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

The closest I came to what I want is:
http://jsfiddle.net/ztuf4gjc/1/

But I feel this is not a good solution, because I need to adjust every other element on the page to make this work and I can foresee some side-effects happening. Also, I want only the timeline section to be scrollable in the x-axis, not the entire page.

Does anyone know how to tackle this issue?

**Update**

Based on @a--m answers, this might not be possible with CSS unfortunately.
Here is the js approach: http://jsfiddle.net/cvk43g1o/

If anyone knows how to do this with CSS, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible to achieve what you ask using CSS only:

> A stickily positioned box is positioned similarly to a relatively positioned box, but the offset is computed with reference to the nearest ancestor with a scrolling box, or the viewport if no ancestor has a scrolling box.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#sticky-pos

Since the parent `timeline` has a horizontal scroll, then the sticky refers to this one and loses the ability to track window as you desire. The limitation to `sticky` in this case is that can't track two different containers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was suspecting something like this was happening,  but it is good to know why exactly. Do you know what would be the best alternative solution? I assume using js scroll event?

Comment: @kingofbbq I can't think of a better alternative, although I don't like the idea of having that being executed everytime the window scrolls... while posting this answer I did some trial and error attempts, and none of them liked me enough to get past into the "answer alternative example". Looking into the [stickyfill Polyfill source](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill/blob/master/src/stickyfill.js#L469) looks like it does something similar.

Comment: Same here... too bad, thanks for investigating though!

Comment: Np @kingofbbq , glad I could help to clarify. Remember to accept answers, and upvote when you think it deserves. Those are the best way to say thanks in SO. Also, a reminder, take a look into the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. It seems like I have not enough reputation yet to upvote. Will do, once this becomes available for me!

Comment: No worries, privileges will come over time. You did a great with your first questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could just copy the contents of `.timeline-header` into `.timeline` and it seems to work as far as I understand the question.

The reason `position: sticky` wouldn't work when applied to `.timeline-header` is because the scroll is dependent on it's containing block and since it takes up most of it's containing block you don't actually see it move before it returns to position relative. When `position: sticky` is applied to `.timeline` the containing block is much larger allowing you to see it scroll throughout the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By making .timeline `position: sticky`, the entire timeline element will become sticky. I just want the timeline-header to stick to the top while scrolling up. Or do you mean something else?